# How to add binding to jndi namespace and later pull it out if possible from code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

Is it possible to add some binding, for example String test = "test string", through Web.xml to jndi bindings pool, to later pull it out in the way:
`new InitialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/test")`
from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer
web.xml

```
...
<env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>java:comp/env/string/stringVar</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>value of the inserted string</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
...
```

the code

```
...
String testString = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/string/stringVar");
...
```